# How to work around conflicts of generic implementations of traits (blanket implementations)?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm coming from C++ and I'm running into issues with generic trait implemntations.

I'm trying to build a geometry library that does some operation on both polygons and open paths, but behaves slightly different for each case. Ideally I want one implementation of a geometry operation as a method which can query the object it's operating on for a flag.

I also want this library to work on any object that can look like a polygon or open path, not just my data types, so I want traits for `PolygonLike` and `OpenPathLike` that can be implemented on any type. I have code that looks like this:

```
trait Clipable {
    fn closed() -> bool;
    fn geom_func(&self) {
        if Self::closed() {
            println!("closed");
        } else {
            println!("open");
        }
    }
}

trait PolygonLike {}
trait OpenPathLike {}

struct Point(f64, f64);
type PointVec = Vec<Point>;
struct Poly(PointVec);
struct Path(PointVec);

impl PolygonLike for Poly {}
impl OpenPathLike for PointVec {}

impl<T> Clipable for T
where
    T: PolygonLike,
{
    fn closed() -> bool {
        true
    }
}

impl<T> Clipable for T
where
    T: OpenPathLike,
{
    fn closed() -> bool {
        false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pg = Poly(PointVec::new());
    let op = Path(PointVec::new());
    pg.geom_func();
    op.geom_func();
}
```

The code fails to compile with:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Clipable`:
  --> src/main.rs:28:1
   |
24 | impl<T> Clipable for T where T: PolygonLike {
   | ------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
28 | impl<T> Clipable for T where T: OpenPathLike {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

I have read elsewhere that the `where` clause isn't used by the conflict checker, even though no type implements both `PolygonLike` and `OpenPathLike`.

I get that this is because a consumer could just implement both those traits and break the library. What I don't get is how I can work around this.

I have seen other posts where people have used newtypes to limit generic implementations, but I can't figure out how to make that work for my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not possible. You will need to implement `Clipable` for `Poly`, `PointVec`, and any others, individually.

You might consider writing macros to make this less repetitive:

```
macro_rules! clipable_poly {
    ($($ty: ty),+) => {
        $(
            impl PolygonLike for $ty {}

            impl Clipable for $ty {
                fn closed() -> bool {
                    true
                }
            }
        )+
    }   
}

macro_rules! clipable_open {
    ($($ty: ty),+) => {
        $(
            impl OpenPathLike for $ty {}

            impl Clipable for $ty {
                fn closed() -> bool {
                    false
                }
            }
        )+
    }   
}

clipable_poly!(Poly, Point);
clipable_open!(PointVec, Path);
```

Comment: *"This is currently not possible"* Do you know if this will be possible in the future (e.g. there is an RFC ongoing, a unstable feature?)

Comment: @hellow With [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), you could do something like that. It is unlikely to be stabilised any time soon though.

Comment: @hellow For example, with specialization, you would be able to make a blanket impl of `Clipable` for all `T`, with `fn closed() { false }`, and then a _more specialized_ impl for `T: PolygonLike` with `fn closed() { true }`.

Comment: That could work. Maybe it'd be better if the blanket implementation just panicked in closed(), and I had a specialization for both PolygonLike and OpenPathLike. It Is frustrating that the limited blanket implementation doesn't work, however. It really limits the ability to delegate from one trait to another.